# Sorting and clustering together arrays or vectors

Tags: c++, c, sorting, vector

I have the following data structure:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::pair <std::vector<unsigned>,std::vector<unsigned> >, unsigned > > A;
```

containing the following data:

```
((7),(108,109)),5
((7),(108,109)),4
((7),(101,102,110)),3
((7),(101,102)),1
((7),(51)),2
((7),(51,54)),6
((7),(40,54,59)),7
((3),(108,109)),15
((3),(101,102,110)),13
((3),(101,102)),11
((3),(51)),12
((3),(51,54)),16
((3),(40,54,59)),17
((9),(108,109)),25
((9),(108,109)),24
((9),(108,109,110)),20
((9),(101,102,110)),23
((9),(111,112,120)),21
((9),(101,102)),29
((9),(51)),22
((9),(51,54)),26
((9),(40,54,59)),7
((8,2,10),(108,109)),25
((8,2,10),(108,109)),24
((8,2,10),(108,109,110)),20
((8,2,10),(101,102,110)),23
((8,2,10),(111,112,120)),21
((8,2,10),(101,102)),29
((8,2,10),(51)),22
((8,2,10),(51,54)),26
((8,2,10),(40,54,59)),7
((5,7),(108,109)),35
((5,7),(108,109)),34
((5,7),(108,109,110)),30
((5,7),(101,102,110)),33
((5,7),(111,112,120)),31
((5,7),(101,102)),39
((5,7),(51)),32
((5,7),(51,54)),36
((5,7),(40,54,59)),37
```

Now I want to arrange my data in the following manner:

```
((3),(101,102)),11
((3),(108,109)),15
((3),(101,102,110)),13
((7),(101,102)),1
((7),(108,109)),5
((7),(108,109)),4
((7),(101,102,110)),3
((9),(101,102)),29
((9),(108,109)),25
((9),(108,109)),24
((9),(101,102,110)),23
((9),(108,109,110)),20
((9),(111,112,120)),21
((5,7),(101,102)),39
((5,7),(108,109)),35
((5,7),(108,109)),34
((5,7),(101,102,110)),33
((5,7),(108,109,110)),30
((5,7),(111,112,120)),31
((8,2,10),(101,102)),29
((8,2,10),(108,109)),25
((8,2,10),(108,109)),24
((8,2,10),(101,102,110)),23
((8,2,10),(108,109,110)),20
((8,2,10),(111,112,120)),21

((3),(51)),12
((3),(51,54)),16
((3),(40,54,59)),17
((7),(51)),2
((7),(51,54)),6
((7),(40,54,59)),7
((9),(51)),22
((9),(51,54)),26
((9),(40,54,59)),7
((5,7),(51)),32
((5,7),(51,54)),36
((5,7),(40,54,59)),37
((8,2,10),(51)),22
((8,2,10),(51,54)),26
((8,2,10),(40,54,59)),7
```

The ordering is achieved by first sorting by size the first vector of the first pair<> in the pair<>. Then lexicographically sorting the vectors. The second vector of the second pair in the pair<> is also sorted first by size of size and then it is lexicographically sorted. The data as a whole is clustered according of the second vector of the first pair<> in the pair<> of vector A. i.e. the user specifies to cluster together all elements of A together according to: ((101,102),(108,109),(101,102,110),(108,109,110),(111,112,120)) and ((51),(51,54),(40,54,59)).

I know it is possible to sort by (i). first size and (ii). then lexicographically sorting the vectors. By using the following code:

```
bool mySort(const pair<vector<unsigned>,vector<unsigned> > &a , const pair<vector<unsigned>,vector<unsigned> > &b)
{
    if (a.first.size() == b.first.size()) {
        //If sizes of the vectors are equal
        //Sort the graph lexicographically. 
        return std::lexicographical_compare(a.first.begin(),a.first.end(),b.first.begin(),b.first.end());pair<vector<unsigned>,vector<unsigned> > a
    } else {
        //Sort by size.
        return a.first.size() < b.first.size();
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::vector<unsigned>,std::vector<unsigned> > > a;
    std::sort(a.begin(),a.end(),mySort);
}
```

But I am not getting that how can I also cluster together the second vector of the first pair of pair of vectors of A while sorting ((i). by size (ii). and then lexicographical ordering). Can someone please help me with it.

Additionally the size of vector A which I have is very large. So, any solutions which can also be efficient will be an icing on the cake.

The version of gcc which I am using is: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

I am fine with if the same could be achieved in c or c++ using any data structure (as I am only interested in the specific ordering that I have specified).

EDIT:  Code for generating input:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::vector<unsigned>, std::vector<unsigned> > > a; 
vector<unsigned> b; vector<unsigned> p;
b.push_back(7); p.push_back(108); p.push_back(109);
a.push_back(make_pair(b,p));
p.clear();
p.push_back(101); p.push_back(102); p.push_back(110);
a.push_back(make_pair(b,p));
p.clear();
p.push_back(101); p.push_back(102);
a.push_back(make_pair(b,p));
p.clear();
p.push_back(51);
a.push_back(make_pair(b,p));
p.clear();
p.push_back(51); p.push_back(54);
a.push_back(make_pair(b,p));
p.clear();
p.push_back(40); p.push_back(54); p.push_back(59);
a.push_back(make_pair(b,p));
b.clear(); p.clear();
b.push_back(3);
p.push_back(108); p.push_back(109); 
a.push_back(make_pair(b,p));
p.clear();
p.push_back(101); p.push_back(102); p.push_back(110);
a.push_back(make_pair(b,p));
p.clear();
p.push_back(101); p.push_back(102); 
a.push_back(make_pair(b,p));
p.clear();
p.push_back(51); 
a.push_back(make_pair(b,p));
p.clear();
p.push_back(51); p.push_back(54);
a.push_back(make_pair(b,p));
p.clear();
p.push_back(40); p.push_back(54); p.push_back(59);
a.push_back(make_pair(b,p));
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have to use `std::partition` after your sort with correct predicate.

Comment: @Jarod42 Can you please explain with the help of an example. I'll be really thankful to you for the same

Comment: @Jarod42 Bingo. You have hit the right function. Thanks you very much :) But I am not getting how can I achieve sorting too and get the output in the above user specified format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may partition first (`std::partition`), then sort each 'cluster' (`std::sort`).

Following may help:

```
using vec_pair = std::pair<std::vector<unsigned>, std::vector<unsigned>>;

std::set<std::vector<unsigned>> wanted = {
    {101,102}, {108,109}, {101,102,110}, {108,109,110}, {111,112,120}};

auto mid = std::partition(a.begin(), a.end(), [&](const vec_pair& p){
    return wanted.count(p.second) != 0;
});

std::sort(a.begin(), mid, mySort); // First cluster
std::sort(mid, a.end(), mySort);   // Second cluster
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/mTPrxq)

The lambda may be replaced by this functor in C++03:

```
struct allowed
{
public:
    explicit allowed(const std::set<std::vector<unsigned>>& wanted) :  wanted(wanted) {}

    bool operator () (const vec_pair& p) const {
        return wanted.count(p.second) != 0;
    }
private:
    const std::set<std::vector<unsigned>>& wanted;
};
```

and the code become:

```
std::vector<vec_pair>::iterator mid = std::partition(a.begin(), a.end(), allowed(wanted));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. But dont you think {{3}, {101, 102}} should come before {{3}, {108, 109}}
{{3}, {101, 102, 110}}. Also I am using  gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3. So I am afraid I am not able to understand what "auto" does, can you please explain this a little.

Comment: I used your sort function unchanged (which check only first part of the pair). And I use a lambda (available since C++11), I will add the corresponding functor.

Comment: Ok..I'll check for the sorting function. Thanks for all your effort and I am sorry I really do not know c++11.

Comment: Here mid performs a binary partition. What if I want to partition at three points?

Comment: why accept an answer you indicated doesn't solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've deleted my first answer because the results wasn't correct.

Ok so your first problem is clearly problem specification.
What you want and what needs to happen is very very unclear tbh.

So here is my understanding of your problem:
You have a collection of data defined by the following data structure:

```
typedef std::vector<unsigned> listType;
typedef std::pair < listType, listType > vectorPair;
typedef std::pair< vectorPair, unsigned> recordType;
std::vector< recordType >  A
```

The problem is to sort A according to the following priorities:

1. Sort according to "cluster" (see definition below)
2. The first list (recordType.first.first) is sorted firstly by size and then lexicographically
3. The second list (recordType.first.second) is sorted firstly by size and then lexicographically
4. Lastly the second value of recordType is used (recordType.second) ?

"clusters" are defined by specific collections of the values in recordType.first.second.
So for this example cluster 1: ((101,102),(108,109),(101,102,110),(108,109,110),(111,112,120)) 
and cluster 2:  ((51),(51,54),(40,54,59))

Ok now that the definition is better sorting this becomes fairly easy by just writing the correct sorting function.

How fast you will sort will mainly depend on how fast you can determine cluster number. For this purpose I've used an unordered_map for near constant time look-ups. (My hash function assumes the values in the second list is smaller than 256 and you won't have 2 many of them, for practical applications you will probably need a much better hash function)

Here is the program:

```
using namespace std;


typedef std::vector<unsigned> listType;
typedef std::pair < listType, listType > vectorPair;
typedef std::pair< vectorPair, unsigned> recordType;
std::vector< recordType >  A = {
    { { { 7 }, { 108, 109 } }, 5 },
    { { { 7 }, { 108, 109 } }, 4 },
    { { { 7 }, { 101, 102, 110 } }, 3 },
    { { { 7 }, { 101, 102 } }, 1 },
    { { { 7 }, { 51 } }, 2 },
    { { { 7 }, { 51, 54 } }, 6 },
    { { { 7 }, { 40, 54, 59 } }, 7 },
    { { { 3 }, { 108, 109 } }, 15 },
    { { { 3 }, { 101, 102, 110 } }, 13 },
    { { { 3 }, { 101, 102 } }, 11 },
    { { { 3 }, { 51 } }, 12 },
    { { { 3 }, { 51, 54 } }, 16 },
    { { { 3 }, { 40, 54, 59 } }, 17 },
    { { { 9 }, { 108, 109 } }, 25 },
    { { { 9 }, { 108, 109 } }, 24 },
    { { { 9 }, { 108, 109, 110 } }, 20 },
    { { { 9 }, { 101, 102, 110 } }, 23 },
    { { { 9 }, { 111, 112, 120 } }, 21 },
    { { { 9 }, { 101, 102 } }, 29 },
    { { { 9 }, { 51 } }, 22 },
    { { { 9 }, { 51, 54 } }, 26 },
    { { { 9 }, { 40, 54, 59 } }, 7 },
    { { { 8, 2, 10 }, { 108, 109 } }, 25 },
    { { { 8, 2, 10 }, { 108, 109 } }, 24 },
    { { { 8, 2, 10 }, { 108, 109, 110 } }, 20 },
    { { { 8, 2, 10 }, { 101, 102, 110 } }, 23 },
    { { { 8, 2, 10 }, { 111, 112, 120 } }, 21 },
    { { { 8, 2, 10 }, { 101, 102 } }, 29 },
    { { { 8, 2, 10 }, { 51 } }, 22 },
    { { { 8, 2, 10 }, { 51, 54 } }, 26 },
    { { { 8, 2, 10 }, { 40, 54, 59 } }, 7 },
    { { { 5, 7 }, { 108, 109 } }, 35 },
    { { { 5, 7 }, { 108, 109 } }, 34 },
    { { { 5, 7 }, { 108, 109, 110 } }, 30 },
    { { { 5, 7 }, { 101, 102, 110 } }, 33 },
    { { { 5, 7 }, { 111, 112, 120 } }, 31 },
    { { { 5, 7 }, { 101, 102 } }, 39 },
    { { { 5, 7 }, { 51 } }, 32 },
    { { { 5, 7 }, { 51, 54 } }, 36 },
    { { { 5, 7 }, { 40, 54, 59 } }, 37 } };




#define MAXVALUE 256
struct myHash
{
    size_t  operator()(const listType& key)
    {
        size_t hash = 0;
        for (unsigned value : key)
        {
            hash = (hash * MAXVALUE) + value;
        }
        return hash;
    }
};

typedef std::unordered_map<listType, int, myHash> clusterHash;

clusterHash clusterNumbers;



int calculateClusterNumber(const listType & list)
{   
    //example code (replace with what you need here)
    clusterHash::const_iterator i = clusterNumbers.find(list);
    if (i == clusterNumbers.end())
        return -1; //not found, return default
    else
        return i->second;
}

bool mySort(const recordType &a, const recordType &b)
{
    //on highest level sort according to cluster number
    int clusterA = calculateClusterNumber(a.first.second);
    int clusterB = calculateClusterNumber(b.first.second);
    if (clusterA == clusterB)
    {
        const std::vector<unsigned> & aa = a.first.first;
        const std::vector<unsigned> & bb = b.first.first;
        //next level of sorting is by size of first vector
        if (aa.size() == bb.size())
        {
            //now do a lexicographically compare of the vectors

            bool r1 = std::lexicographical_compare(aa.begin(), aa.end(), bb.begin(), bb.end());         
            if (r1) return true;
            bool r2 = std::lexicographical_compare(bb.begin(), bb.end(), aa.begin(), aa.end());
            if (r2) return false;

            //at this stage they are equal so continue to compare the second set of vectors: (first by size
            const std::vector<unsigned> & aa2 = a.first.second;
            const std::vector<unsigned> & bb2 = b.first.second;
            if (aa2.size() == bb2.size())
            {

                bool r1 = std::lexicographical_compare(aa2.begin(), aa2.end(), bb2.begin(), bb2.end());
                if (r1) return true;
                bool r2 = std::lexicographical_compare(bb2.begin(), bb2.end(), aa2.begin(), aa2.end());
                if (r2) return false;


                //if they also similar the last comparison is for the second value of the top-level pair in record:
                return a.second < b.second;

            }
            else
            {
                return aa2.size() < bb2.size();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return aa.size() < bb.size();
        }


    }
    else
    {
        //cluster ordering
        return clusterA < clusterB;
    }
    return false;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    //setup the clusters:
    clusterNumbers.insert({ {101,102}, 1 });
    clusterNumbers.insert({ { 108, 109 }, 1 });
    clusterNumbers.insert({ { 101, 102, 110 }, 1 });
    clusterNumbers.insert({ { 108, 109, 110 }, 1 });
    clusterNumbers.insert({ { 111, 112, 120 }, 1 });
    clusterNumbers.insert({ { 51 }, 2 });
    clusterNumbers.insert({ { 51, 54 }, 2 });
    clusterNumbers.insert({ { 40,54,59 }, 2 });

    std::sort(A.begin(), A.end(), mySort);

    for (recordType & r : A)
    {
        auto printList = [](const listType & l) {for (unsigned u : l)std::cout << u << ","; };

        std::cout << "(";
        printList(r.first.first);
        std::cout << "),(";     
        printList(r.first.second);
        std::cout << ")," << r.second <<  std::endl;
    }



    char c;
    cin >> c;

    return 0;
}
```

In terms of speed this will be close to O(n. log(n))
However with very large arrays all the lexicographical_compare functions might slow things down a little.

It would be interesting to see if doing a linear O(n) partition or sort of only the clusters will be faster, my suspicion is that it won't really help.
However what might help slightly is to pre-compute the cluster numbers but this require you to modify the data structure.

Lastly from my search it shows that GCC 4.6 does support rvalues so I'm assuming the swapping inside the search will be efficient and not result in a ton of memcpy's.

I've tested this and it seems to spit out the correct results.
(I'm using Visual Studio 2013)